# How can we get list of default indexes on primary keys used by PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, psql

I want a list of default indexes built on primary keys of table used by PostgreSQL for query processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html

```
SELECT 
    conname, contype, conindid::regclass 
FROM 
    pg_constraint 
WHERE 
    contype = 'p';
```

Where `conindid::regclass` is the index name.

Comment: Thanks for the doc link, they helped me for understanding, but the above code didn't return anything.

Comment: Then you don't have `PRIMARY KEYs` on your tables in whatever database you ran this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RELNAME,
    RELKIND
FROM PG_CLASS
WHERE RELKIND = 'i';
```

##### This is command is in PostgreSQL DB, and it Will list all the indexes that got created by default when you created a Unique column or Primary Key.